# Get the phone number in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

It seems I cannot find any information if it is possible to programatically get the phone number (from the SIM card) in Windows Phone 8. I am able to get information about my contacts, but cannot get my own phone number. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current SDK.

Comment: I was afraid of that...